# Dynamically adding and remove UI

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to dynamically and remove modules within a module. In this dummy example, inner module has button and numeric input which is active if button has odd value and returns numeric value:

```
module1UI <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("btn"),
      label = "click"
    ),
    numericInput(
      inputId = ns("num"),
      label = "value",
      value = 0
    ),
    textOutput(ns("txt"))
  )
}

module1Server <- function(id)
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      
      btn_active <- reactive({
        req(input$btn)
        (input$btn %% 2 != 0)
      })
      
      observeEvent(btn_active(), {
        my_move <- if(btn_active()) shinyjs::show else shinyjs::hide
        my_move("num")
      })
      
      my_value <- reactive({
        if(btn_active()) input$num else NULL
      })
      
      output$txt <- renderText({
        paste("id:", id, "|", if(isTruthy(btn_active())) my_value() else "CLICK", sep = " ")
      })
      
      my_value
    }
  )
```

Outer module dynamically adds or removes inner module by clicking buttons:

```
module2UI <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  div(
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("add"),
      label = "Add Input"
    ),
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("remove"),
      label = "Remove Input",
    ),
    align = "center",
    br(),
    div(
      id = ns("add_here"),
      style = "align:center;"
    )
  )
}

module2Server <- function(id)
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session){
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(value_list = list(), id_vec = character(0))
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    observeEvent(input$add, ignoreNULL = TRUE, {
      
      new_input_id <- paste0("input", input$add)
      print(new_input_id)
      rv$id_vec <- c(new_input_id, rv$id_vec)
      
      insertUI(
        selector = paste0("#", ns("add_here")),
        ui = module1UI(new_input_id)
      )
      
      observeEvent(module1Server(new_input_id), {
        rv$value_list[[new_input_id]] <- module1Server(new_input_id)
      })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$remove, {
      
      last_id <- rv$id_vec[[1]]
      rv$value_list[[last_id]] <- NULL
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#", last_id))
      removeShinyInputs(ns(last_id), input)
      rv$id_vec <- rv$id_vec[-1]
    })
    
    observeEvent(rv$id_vec, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
      
      has_input <- (length(rv$id_vec) > 0)
      my_move <- if(!has_input) shinyjs::disable else shinyjs::enable
      my_move("remove")
    })
    
    reactive(rv$value_list)
  })
```

with removing function:

```
removeShinyInputs <- function(id, .input){
  
  invisible(
    lapply(
      grep(id, names(.input), value = TRUE),
      function(i) .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values$remove(i)
    )
  )
}
```

When added dynamically inner modules are not reactive at all:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  module2UI("my_module"),
  textOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  value_list <- module2Server("my_module")

  output$txt <- renderText({
    
    if(length(value_list()) == 0) 
      return("empty")
    
    my_vec <- purrr::map_dbl(value_list(), ~.x())
    print(my_vec)
    
    as.character(my_vec)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

but inner module works just fine by its own:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  module1UI("1"),
  textOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input, output, server){

  value <- module1Server("1")
  output$text <- renderText({
    if(isTruthy(value)) as.character(value) else "BANANA"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. How to dynamically add modules that are reactive?
   (but within module, it seems this would work if not wrapped within module)
2. Remove UI currently does not work, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve 1, you can use `ns` when inserting UI.

```
insertUI(
          selector = paste0("#", ns("add_here")),
          ui = module1UI(ns(new_input_id))
        )
```

To resolve 2, you could put the insertUI in a `div()`, so that you can remove it.

```
insertUI(
          selector = paste0("#", ns("add_here")),
          ui = div( module1UI(ns(new_input_id)), id = ns(new_input_id)    )  ##########   <---------
        )
```

Full code (no change in module1UI):

```
module2UI <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  div(
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("add"),
      label = "Add Input"
    ),
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("remove"),
      label = "Remove Input",
    ),
    align = "center",
    br(),
    div(
      id = ns("add_here"),
      style = "align:center;"
    )
  )
}

module2Server <- function(id)
  moduleServer(
    id, 
    function(input, output, session){
      
      rv <- reactiveValues(value_list = list(), id_vec = character(0))
      ns <- NS(id)
      
      observeEvent(input$add, ignoreNULL = TRUE, {
        
        new_input_id <- paste0("input", input$add)
        print(ns(new_input_id))
        rv$id_vec <- c(new_input_id, rv$id_vec)
        
        insertUI(
          selector = paste0("#", ns("add_here")),
          ui = div( module1UI(ns(new_input_id)), id = ns(new_input_id)    )  ##########   <---------
        )
        
        # observeEvent(module1Server(new_input_id), {
          rv$value_list[[new_input_id]] <- module1Server(new_input_id)
        # })
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$remove, {
        
        last_id <- ns(rv$id_vec[[1]])
        print(last_id)
        rv$value_list[[last_id]] <- NULL
        removeUI(selector = sprintf("#%s", last_id))
        removeShinyInputs(ns(last_id), input)
        rv$id_vec <- rv$id_vec[-1]
      })
      
      observeEvent(rv$id_vec, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
        
        has_input <- (length(rv$id_vec) > 0)
        my_move <- if(!has_input) shinyjs::disable else shinyjs::enable
        my_move("remove")
      })
      
      # reactive(rv$value_list)
      return(rv)
    }
)

removeShinyInputs <- function(id, .input){
  
  invisible(
    lapply(
      grep(id, names(.input), value = TRUE),
      function(i) .subset2(.input, "impl")$.values$remove(i)
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  module2UI("my_module"),
  textOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  values <- module2Server("my_module")
  
  output$txt <- renderText({
    if(length(values$value_list) == 0) 
    #if(length(value_list()) == 0) 
      return("empty")
    
    my_vec <- purrr::map_dbl(values$value_list, ~.x())
    print(my_vec)
    
    as.character(my_vec)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Good point with the `div`. Alternatively, you could also use the `div` instead of the `tagList` in `module1UI`.